# Reliably checking whether NSDate falls within given hour, day or week

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to take a stored NSDate and reliably determine whether it falls within the current moment's hour, day or week. I seem to have hacked together a solution, but not having solved this problem before, am not entirely confident that it's a reliable one.

Will this survive user-set 12 vs 24 hour time? [the date formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html%20the%20date%20formatting%20guide) indicates that this user setting can lead to some unanticipated date behavior: *"In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set."*

What about the basic code pattern for this problem? Does this code seem to reliably serve its purpose? I hate to post a "check my code" sort of question, but it's an unfamiliar-enough problem to me, and tricky enough to rigorously test, that it seemed justified. NSDateFormatter is also relatively new to me; another motivation for the question.

**NOTE: The main source of my nervousness is that converting dates to strings and then doing a string compare seems an inherently fragile method of solving this problem. But it's the best I could come up with.**

Quick reference: the `dateFormat`s I used for each of the three cases were:

```
dateFormat = @"yyyyMMddHH"; // For "this hour" check
dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd"; // For "today" check
dateFormat = @"yyyyww"; // For "this week" check
```

Thanks! Code Follows:

```
- (BOOL)didThisCycle {
    // Case 1: hourly; Case 2: daily; Case 3: weekly
    BOOL did = NO;

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *lastDid = [self.didDates lastObject];

    if (![lastDid isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) { // Crash protection
        return NO;
    }

    int type = [self.goalType intValue];
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
        {
            // If hourly check hour
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMddHH";
            NSString *nowString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
            NSString *lastDidString = [formatter stringFromDate:lastDid];
            if ([nowString isEqualToString:lastDidString]) {
                did = YES;
            } else {
                did = NO;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            // If daily check day
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd";
            NSString *nowString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
            NSString *lastDidString = [formatter stringFromDate:lastDid];
            if ([nowString isEqualToString:lastDidString]) {
                did = YES;
            } else {
                did = NO;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            // If weekly check week
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyww";
            NSString *nowString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
            NSString *lastDidString = [formatter stringFromDate:lastDid];
            if ([nowString isEqualToString:lastDidString]) {
                did = YES;
            } else {
                did = NO;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            did = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    return did;
}
```

Comment: "converting dates to strings and then doing a string compare seems an inherently fragile method" <- It is. You should make the user enter the date in a unique, perferrably structured format - for example, if your program has a GUI, you can use an UIDatePicker object.

Comment: Well, they're not user-entered dates. The program is storing the dates of certain program events, etc. So these dates are almost always (aka always) created via [NSDate date] at the moment of some event. But the problem then becomes how to test whether an NSDate falls within a given range (in this case, the current hour, day or week). e.g. An event happened at 1:02 PM. It's now 1:56 PM so if we're checking hourly (case 1) this should return true. At 2:01 PM it should return false, etc.

Comment: in this case it's elementary math, provided that NSDate has methods of retrieving the components (hour, day, week) of the date. AFAIK it has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the NSDateComponents class, like so:

```
NSDate *someDate = // whatever
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *thenComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:someDate];
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
if([thenComponents year] == [nowComponents year] && [thenComponents month] == [nowComponents month] && [thenComponents day] == [nowComponents day] && [thenComponents hour] == [nowComponents hour])
{
    // hooray
}
```

Remove the “hour” component if you just want to check the day, or remove both that and “day” (and replace with `NSWeekCalendarUnit` and the `-week` method) to check the week.

Comment: Thanks Noah, that worked great. Wasn't aware of the components functions.